# How to remove a subdocument from a document, WHERE condition x = true OR condition y = true?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Below is a referenced subdocument called Bets that is embedded into an array of a property on another model called Users. When a user deletes a friend, all associated bets with that specific user should be deleted from the User document as well (the user who was friends with the now deleted other user).

I am looking for the query to do so. First, here is the specific bet instance.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5817cc81233ef74d418d5a1f"),
    "amount" : 50,
    "name" : "Redskins vs Cowboys",
    "description" : "let's see who wins this game",
    "status" : "requested",
    "requestee" : {
        "user" : ObjectId("5817a417146dbb4b380ad1b2"),
        "winnerVote" : null
    },
    "requestor" : {
        "user" : ObjectId("5817a41e146dbb4b380ad1b3"),
        "winnerVote" : null
    },
    "__v" : 0
}
```

So far, this is my destroy friendship controller:

```
destroy: function(req, res) {
    User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id,
    { $pull: { "friendships": {"friend": req.params.friendId } }, $pull: { "bets": {"requestee.id": req.params.friendId ****OR**** "requestor.id": req.params.friendId}} }, function(err, user) {
      if (err) {
        res.send({error: err});
      } else {
        User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.friendId,
          { $pull: { "friendships": {"friend": req.params.id } } }, function(err, user) {
            if (err) {
              res.send({error: err})
            } else {

              res.status(200).send();
            }
          }
        )
      }
    })
  }
```

As you can see, after the first `'findByIDandUpdate'` query, I have two `$pull` commands. The second one is where I am attempting to implement this new query I am trying to produce.

I would like to PULL BETS, where `bet.requesteEE.user === oldFriendID` OR (||) PULL BETS, where `bet.requestOR.user === oldFriendID`

Comment: There is the $or operator which takes an array of documents to match the expression, can you try the following:

     $pull: { $or: [ { "bets": {"requestee.id": friendId } }, { "bets": { "requestor.id": friendId } } ] } 

I'm not sure if that is valid syntax for an update operator, you may need to use elemMatch.

You'll also optionally want { multi : true } as your 3rd operator if you want to do the update on more than one document.

Comment: Didn't seem to work with the $or operator but thank you I definitely appreciate the response :)

Answer (score 0):

You might have to handle this in the Mongoose Callback - see if this works:

```
User.findById(req.params.id, function(err, user) {
    // for each bet in user.bets
    user.bets.forEach(function(bet) {
        if (bet.requestee === friendId || bet.requester === friendId) {
            delete bet;
        }
    });
    user.save();
    // Handle response logic here or in the save callback.

});
```